# An extra signer with status as "created" is getting along with other signers

Tags: api, docusignapi, envelope, docusignconnect, signer

I created an envelope using Docusign API with status as sent and I had two signers in it. But when I actually checked in the account - there is one extra signer with the same name added along with the other signers in the envelope.[Envelope Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YejXC.png)

I also checked the same while calling the recipients API and here also it had 3 signers and the extra one had status as created. [Recipient API response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfrmP.png) But I referred [doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kD9Bh.png) it said created recipients are only for Envelope who is in Draft state. so how can the signer of status sent and created be added together?

Not sure how this extra signer got added. Any inputs will be appreciated.

my json request to generate envelope Id

```
    {
   "status":"Sent",
   "emailSubject":"Your Amboy Documents",
   "emailBlurb":"Please sign the Disclosures",
   "compositeTemplates":[
      {
         "serverTemplates":[
            {
               "templateId":"1b890a65-ce07-40a7-9086-3be315de6f4f",
               "sequence":"1"
            }
         ],
         "inlineTemplates":[
            {
               "sequence":"1",
               "recipients":{
                  "signers":[
                     {
                        "tabs":{
                           "textTabs":[
                              {
                                 "value":"laptop services",
                                 "tabLabel":"Party_Business_ENTName"
                              }
                           ],
                           "checkboxTabs":[
                              {
                                 "value":"X",
                                 "tabLabel":"App_1_BT_CORP",
                                 "selected":"true"
                              }
                           ]
                        },
                        "roleName":"Signer 1",
                        "recipientId":"2",
                        "partyId":"a0uR00000043CfMIAU",
                        "name":"rafeeq khan",
                        "emailNotification":null,
                        "email":"kshama.vaidya@terafinainc.com",
                        "clientUserId":"2"
                     },
                     {
                        "tabs":{
                           "textTabs":[
                              {
                                 "value":"laptop services",
                                 "tabLabel":"Party_Business_ENTName"
                              }
                           ],
                           "checkboxTabs":[
                              {
                                 "value":"X",
                                 "tabLabel":"App_1_BT_CORP",
                                 "selected":"true"
                              }
                           ]
                        },
                        "roleName":"Signer 2",
                        "recipientId":"3",
                        "partyId":"a0uR00000043CiRIAU",
                        "name":"Imam khan",
                        "emailNotification":null,
                        "email":"kshama.vaidya@terafinainc.com",
                        "clientUserId":"3"
                     }
                  ],
                  "carbonCopies":[
                     
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "serverTemplates":[
            {
               "templateId":"0b69b96b-6746-470c-9032-06bff16d98e2",
               "sequence":"2"
            }
         ],
         "inlineTemplates":[
            {
               "sequence":"2",
               "recipients":{
                  "signers":[
                     {
                        "tabs":{
                           "textTabs":[
                              {
                                 "value":"rafeeq khan",
                                 "tabLabel":"Party_1_Name"
                              }
                           ],
                           "checkboxTabs":[
                              
                           ]
                        },
                        "roleName":"Signer 600",
                        "recipientId":"2",
                        "partyId":"a0uR00000043CfMIAU",
                        "name":"rafeeq khan",
                        "emailNotification":null,
                        "email":"kshama.vaidya@terafinainc.com",
                        "clientUserId":"2"
                     }
                  ],
                  "carbonCopies":[
                     
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "serverTemplates":[
            {
               "templateId":"0e3fc453-a721-46bb-837d-7b5408e4384b",
               "sequence":"3"
            }
         ],
         "inlineTemplates":[
            {
               "sequence":"3",
               "recipients":{
                  "signers":[
                     {
                        "tabs":{
                           "textTabs":[
                              {
                                 "value":"rafeeq khan",
                                 "tabLabel":"Party_1_Name"
                              }
                           ],
                           "checkboxTabs":[
                              
                           ]
                        },
                        "roleName":"Signer 1",
                        "recipientId":"2",
                        "partyId":"a0uR00000043CfMIAU",
                        "name":"rafeeq khan",
                        "emailNotification":null,
                        "email":"kshama.vaidya@terafinainc.com",
                        "clientUserId":"2"
                     },
                     {
                        "tabs":{
                           "textTabs":[
                              {
                                 "value":"rafeeq khan",
                                 "tabLabel":"Party_1_Name"
                              }
                           ],
                           "checkboxTabs":[
                              
                           ]
                        },
                        "roleName":"Signer 2",
                        "recipientId":"3",
                        "partyId":"a0uR00000043CiRIAU",
                        "name":"Imam khan",
                        "emailNotification":null,
                        "email":"kshama.vaidya@terafinainc.com",
                        "clientUserId":"3"
                     }
                  ],
                  "carbonCopies":[
                     
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "accountId":"11931216"
}
```

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: updated the description with the threuest json to generate envelope Id

Comment: You have multiple templates, how many recipients in each of these templates?

Comment: The extra recipient must be coming from one of your server templates.

Comment: but in that 2 of them have same clientuserid right. it is one only

Comment: even if you have the same clientuserid you may still have different recipients. How many recipients are in each of these templates? how many do you want to be total?